# How to extract a date (yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss) from a string using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am a new bee to powershell, stuck with extracting the date from the below string

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\logs\pg10\postgresql-Sun.log:12:2018-04-08 23:34:08 UTC [4052]: [1-1] user=testdb,db=tests,app=pgAdmin 4 - DB:postgres,client=45.45.45.45,sqlstate=00000,cmd=LOG:  QUERY STATISTICS".
```

I need to extract the date "2018-04-08 23:34:08" from the above string, Could some help me pls.
tried regex such as below:

```
$regex = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"
$r = $log_result -match $regex
```

But this gives me true and false instead of the value.

Help would be a great appreciation.

Thanks Yogi B

Comment: And what does `$Matches[0]` say?

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor, $Matches[0] provides me the extracted date.